# (change) when other radiobutton is checked

Tags: html, angular

I have two **radio buttons**. I need to fire an event when button *B* is `checked` or `unchecked`. I can not bind any event to *A*.

```
<input type="radio" id="A" name="radiogrp" value="A">
<label for="A">A</label>
<input type="radio" id="B" name="radiogrp" value="B" (change)="showOrHideElement()">
<label for="B">B</label>
```

It just works when the button *B* is checked, the event is not fired when I click on the other button.
How can I listen to button changes of *B* without binding anything to *A*?

Comment: Upload your code to stackblitz. Watch this video, youtube.com/watch?v=acDFvTPMKxM

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/07rhpL3k/, it depends on the precise requirements of why you "*cannot bind any event to A*" though.

Comment: Because A and B are dynamically generated from the database. A is a radiobutton which is used in many other places in the form where no eventbinding is needed / allowed. B is a radiobuttonwithtextboxevent which is generated with an event.

ATM I build a work around with a new type, radiobuttonwithtextboxHIDEevent so I can bind something to A. But now I have a lot of duplicate Code with just a minor difference. Works, but is not so cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ngModelChange when you use ngModel everytime the value change the `log()` method will run.

```
<input type="radio" id="A" name="radiogrp" value="A" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="log()">
<label for="A">A</label>
<input type="radio" id="B" name="radiogrp" value="B"[(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="log()" >
<label for="B">B</label>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsrasc)

in case you want to run the method if the B is selected you can just bind the event to the B element

```
<input type="radio" id="A" name="radiogrp" value="A" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" >
<label for="A">A</label>
<input type="radio" id="B" name="radiogrp" value="B"[(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="log()" >
<label for="B">B</label>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re1joy)

other option you can use reactive forms as a simple example using `Form Control`

```
<input type="radio" id="A" name="radiogrp" value="A" [formControl]="selection">
<label for="A">A</label>
<input type="radio" id="B" name="radiogrp" value="B" [formControl]="selection" >
<label for="B">B</label>
```

component

```js
  selection= new FormControl('A')

  ngOnInit(){
      this.selection.valueChanges.subscribe(value =>{

        if (value == 'B') {
        console.log(`B is selected  `,value)
        } else {

        console.log(`B is not selected  `,value)
        }
      })
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9cysp)

Comment: That did not quite hit the mark. I want to run the method every time B is selected and B is unselected. And as mentioned, I can not bind anything to A